# Scala parse a JSON into a Map alternatives

Tags: java, json, scala, pattern-matching

I'm looking for alternatives to scala JSON.parseFull(jsonString). 
I'm using scala JSON to convert jsonString to a Map[String,Any] but sometimes it takes too long to convert it to a map, and build a java object from it. 
jsonString is a long json response.

**Do you know fastest ways to convert a jsonString to a map[String, Any] so I can do patternMatching after that?**

here goes some code with JSON.parseFull():

```
override def parse(in: String): ResponseObject = {

val json: Option[Any] = JSON.parseFull(in)
json match {
  case Some(value) =>
    val map: Map[String, Any] = value.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
    //json root
    val data: Map[String, Any] = map.get("data").get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
    //populate PsmSearchResponse  
    val response: ResponseObject = new ResponseObject
    //mapping base properties
    response.setHash(data.get("hash").get.asInstanceOf[String])
    //call "transformToPsmItem" function to map each Searchitem
    val items: List[ResponseObjectItem] = data.get("items").get.asInstanceOf[List[Any]] map { itemParser.transformToResponseObjectItemItem }
    response.setItems(new ArrayList(items.asJavaCollection))

    //return complete PsmSearchResponse
    response

  case (None) => null
}
```

I have also tried this with lift-json but as I'm using scala 2.10 I cant make it work.

```
val record = json.JsonParser.parse(json)
val json : Option[Any] = record.values.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
```

I'm getting an error about incompatibility of my scala version (2.10) and json-lift version.

I would like to know if is worth trying  libraries and dealing with their problems just to get a little time improvement... so if anybody knows the fastes way please tell me.

Thanks !

Comment: Related link: [Comparing Scala JSON Libraries](http://engineering.ooyala.com/blog/comparing-scala-json-libraries)

Comment: thanks for the link ! it was very usefull , if you have a link with the workarrounds that you mention in te article to deserealize to a Map[String, Any] in Json4s would be very nice !.

Comment: I'm not related with this article.

Comment: well, thanks anyway, that article was exactly what I was looking for.